# "I have been in a six-year-long relationship." I want to know whether the usage of "have been in" correct here, if the relationship ended recently?

Tags: phrase-meaning, present-perfect, idiomatic-language, indian-english, implication

Doesn't the above quoted sentence imply that the person is describing that he/she belongs to the category of people who have been in a relationship atleast once in their lifetime?(irrespective of whether or not the relationship is still continued in the present)
Also, what would the sentence "I have been in a relationship." imply? Does it suggest that the relationship is definitely continued in the present or could it have ended recently?

Comment: I think that if the relationship was continuing the speaker would be more likely to say "I've been in a relationship for six years", so to me _six-year-long_ suggests that it is over (and _have been_ that it is recently over).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is more appropriate? "I was married" OR "I have been married"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294788/which-is-more-appropriate-i-was-married-or-i-have-been-married)

Comment: @KateBunting yeah exactly what I think!